# Jsoup not displaying tags using the select() function

Tags: html, web-scraping, jsoup

I'm trying to scrape the team win-loss record data from the NBA website [here](http://espn.go.com/nba/scoreboard/_/date/20160315). Here's an image of the lines of text I want to capture, it is circled in black:

[image]

Can someone try scraping this exact data and seeing if it works? I've been at it for hours and nothing is working. I was able to scrape the team names and start times but when I try using jsoup's select function on the record lines, I get 0 results back. It's as if the tags are hidden from the html hierarchy. Is this possible? I'm new to this and I may be doing something wrong.

Code I have tried:

```
Document document = Jsoup.connect("http://espn.go.com/nba/scoreboard/_/date/20160315").get();
            games = document.select("section.sb-score");

            for(Element game : games)
            {
                mHomeTeam = game.select("td.home").select("div.sb-meta").text();
                Elements test = game.select("p.record.overall");
                mAwayTeam = game.select("td.away").select("div.sb-meta").text();
                mHomeTeamRecord = game.select("td.home").select("div.record-container").select("p.record").text();
                mAwayTeamRecord = game.select("td.away").select("div.record-container").select("p.record").text();
                mGameStartTime = game.select("span.time").text();

                Game newGameObj = new Game(mHomeTeam, mAwayTeam, mGameStartTime, mHomeTeamRecord, mAwayTeamRecord);
                mGameList.add(newGameObj);
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The team win-loss record data is loaded by Javascript in the page. Since Jsoup is an HTML parser this is why it's not displaying tags with the select() method.

However, it seems this data is located inside the page directly in a Javascript object called `window.espn.scoreboardData`.

Here is how to extract this data:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://espn.go.com/nba/scoreboard/_/date/20160315").get();

for(Element script : doc.select("script")) {
    String scriptData = script.html();
    if (scriptData.contains("window.espn.scoreboardData")) {
        // Parse scriptData to extract team win-loss record ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain how you knew this data was inside a Javascript object? I can't find `window.espn.scoreboardData` anywhere in the html code. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Ghost_Stark Go to http://espn.go.com/nba/scoreboard/_/date/20160315 with your browser. Show the source code and search for "window.espn.scoreboardData". It is located in the last script element before `</head>`.

Comment: Cool, I guess I overlooked it. But how did you know this data was loaded through a Javascript object? Is that what I should expect when I parse through the data and get no results, even when the html is clearly shown in the source?

Comment: @Ghost_Stark Usually, if the html is clearly shown and Jsoup can't find it, it means the html is loaded by another mean: Javascript and  iframe come first in my mind. The html you see in the browser is the *rendered* html and not the *raw* html. This last one is fetched by Jsoup.